# Установка модуля python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pip

Использую PyCharm с интерпретатором python, импортирую Telebot, использую декораторы, чтобы отлавливать события и если запускать в PyCharm, то всё, отлично работает, но если попытаться запустить через консоль (`python bot.py`), то пишет следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Попробовал в консоли написать `pip install telebot`, пишет, что модуль уже установлен

Comment: Попробуй поставь дополнительно этот пакет и запусти `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, Xybyyn!

> поставь дополнительно этот пакет и запусти `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`